# How to make a ArrayList using Javassist

Tags: java, arraylist, instrumentation

I want to add a arrayList into a method during instrumentation. I tried it as mentioned in ([Javassist CannotCompileException when trying to add a line to create a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279914/javassist-cannotcompileexception-when-trying-to-add-a-line-to-create-a-map)) but it throws a different exception with a java.lang.VerifyError.

```
    public void createInsertBefore(String scenarioName, String className, CtMethod method,
                                   String insertBefore) throws CannotCompileException {
        method.addLocalVariable("startTime", CtClass.longType);
        StringBuilder bBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        bBuilder.append("startTime = System.nanoTime();");
        bBuilder.append("System.out.println(startTime);");

        if((insertBefore!=null) && !insertBefore.isEmpty()){
            bBuilder.append(insertBefore);
        }

        bBuilder.append("java.util.List metadata = new java.util.ArrayList();");

        System.out.println(bBuilder.toString());
        method.insertBefore(bBuilder.toString());
}
```

Output received from the print statement is,

```
startTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(startTime);
java.util.List metadata = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

But it throws following exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:382)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:397)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
    at org.wso2.das.javaagent.instrumentation.Agent.premain(Agent.java:57)
    ... 6 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The situation is same as earlier, but why does it throw a different exception. What am i doing wrong....some help please...

**Update 1**

lines added with (I have removed some print lines),
 **insertBefore**,

```
 startTime = System.nanoTime();
 java.util.List metadata = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

**insertAt**

```
System.out.println("prepareStatement is running");
java.util.Map/*<String,String>*/ arbitraryMap = new java.util.HashMap/*String,String>*/();
arbitraryMap.put("query",$1);System.out.println(arbitraryMap);
```

**insertAfter**

```
System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-startTime);
```

Comment: Looks like an error in native code.

Comment: What you mean? U mean the rest of the code? I thought that the problem is with that statement, because if i comment out that line, instrumentation works fine. Therefore i think it is something wrong with that statement.

Comment: Your code might be wrong but the error occurs here: `sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)` i.e. it's within native code. The JavaDoc on the error you get says: `Thrown when the "verifier" detects that a class file, though well formed, contains some sort of internal inconsistency or security problem.` - it might depend on the class that is being enhanced, maybe you're trying to insert twice or there already is a variable called `startTime`, `metadata` etc.

Comment: This is driving me nuts, when i remove the line of creating List it works fine. But again, when i keep that line and remove the (startTime line in insertAfter as given in the above update) it again work fine. But when i keep both it gives the exception. This is really confusing.

Comment: Btw, why are you creating a local variable for `startTime` but add and `metadata` as a string command? I don't know Javassist that well so this might be the only way to do that - it's just a guess since if one works but not both there must be a difference that introduces the incompatibility.

Comment: What contains the *insertBefore* variable?

Comment: The code shared above is perfectly fine. I have copy pasted the code and it worked without any exception. You might have exception somewhere in premain method. Can you post your premain method code? That will help to analyze more on the issue.

Comment: Well um sorry this question is posted long ago and I no longer have the code,  because I decided not to use the arrayList.

Answer (score 7):

A `VerifyError` occurs when the VM notices, that an already compiled bytecode is not valid. For example, when you try to read a long variable using a load instruction for an integer, or similar things.

So, in your case, the code compiles, javaassist does its magic, but the VM does not accept the code. It must be either a bug in javassist or a bug in its usage.

How to fix it:

1) As far as I know, you can only add one statement (not one line) at the beginning of a method using `insertBefore`. If you want to add more than one, wrap them in braces `{}`, something like `method.insertBefore("{" + bBuilder.toString() + "}"`);

2) You did not add the metadata as a variable like you did with `startTime`

X) If this or another error still persists, try to write the class file to a file on disk (using `toClassFile` you can access the modified class file as a `byte[]`). Then you can use tools like javap to look at the compiled code, and see more clearly what is going on.